# Parse error on input `='. Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have defined a following class in Haskell

```
class Ord a => X a where 
    r :: (a, a) -> [a]        


instance (X a, X b) => X (a,b)
    (*)r ((a,b), (c,d)) = r' ((a,b), (c,d)) b where
        r' ((a, b), (c,d)) b'
            | a == c && b == d = (a,b)
            | b < d = (a,b) : (r' ((a, succ b), (c, d)) b')
            | otherwise = (a,b) : (r' ((succ a, b'), (c,d)) b')
```

I got error `parse error on input`='` in line (*)

I don't know how to repair it. Help me please.

Comment: What does this mean: `(*)r ((a,b), (c,d))` ? That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: guess he meant to mark the line that the error message refers to.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 Thanks, i get that now.  It would be better if it wasn't indicated that way as it's quite confusing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some errors which I can see:

- <s>This isn't correct: `(*)r ((a,b), (c,d))`. Perhaps you meant this: `r ((a,b), (c,d))`</s> The OP was indicating the line using that terminology.
- Your instance definition misses the keyword `where`. It should be defined like this:
  `instance (X a, X b) => X (a,b) where`
- The type of the function `r` indicates that it returns a list `[a]`. But in the first clause of your definition of `r'`, you are returning a tuple which isn't correct. Perhaps, you want to do this:

  ```
    r' ((a, b), (c,d)) b'
        | a == c && b == d = [(a,b)]
  ```
- Since you are using the function `succ`, the type variable `a` and `b` should be of `Enum` instances.

Fixing all the above error, gives this code which typechecks:

```
instance (X a, Enum a, Enum b, X b) => X (a,b) where
    r ((a,b), (c,d)) = r' ((a,b), (c,d)) b 
        where
          r' ((a, b), (c,d)) b'
              | a == c && b == d = [(a,b)]
              | b < d = (a,b) : (r' ((a, succ b), (c, d)) b')
              | otherwise = (a,b) : (r' ((succ a, b'), (c,d)) b')
```

Comment: Yes yes yes but I do think that giving a hint is more useful than a complete solution. The guy only asked for the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
instance C T where
   foo = bar where
      bar = ...
```

The first `where` is missing.